# MUPX Production Logs MeteorJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

I have a MeteorJS app using Mupx.

This is less stable version that uses Docker to deploy. Now that I have deployed it, I am wondering how one can get access to the server logs.

In the non-Docker version, apparently you just run `mup logs -f`, but it's not properly documented as how to do so with the Docker variant.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I have since discovered you can use docker commands directly:

`docker ps` will show the id of your application.
`docker logs -f ${id}` will tail the logs.

Answer (score 2):

Mupx githup [page](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#other-utility-commands) claims that 'mupx logs -f' should work.